# With + adverb structure

Tags: grammar, adverbs

The strange example makes me confused - **with + adverb** : "**Red items need dealing with immediately after the process...**"

How correct and common of this structure?

Comment: It's fine: *with* belongs with *dealing*, not the adverb. Would you understand it better if it had been written "Red items need to be dealt with immediately ..."?

Comment: I see the documentation - it says so. And I doubt `need dealing`... Is it an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue which makes it sound strange is not *with* + adverb; it's *-ing* + adverb. In this case, *need* behaves as a modal verb and should be followed by an infintive form.

To *deal with* (something) is a phrasal verb, and there's not really much you can do about the *with*. It's part of the verb and needs to be there.

> Red items need to be dealt with immediately after the process.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that is a part of a verb phrase. :)

Comment: When there is a preposition after a verb, **always** suspect a phrasal verb. They are probably at least as common as non-phrasal verbs, and there are certainly more of them.